# Duplicate rows even though used DISTINCT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm getting duplicate rows from this query, would be grateful for some help please.

```
select

Id_num
Street
Town
Incidents
IncidentType A
IncidentType B
IncidentType C

FROM OPENQUERY
(POSTGRESQL, 
Id_num
Street
Town
Incidents
IncidentType A
IncidentType B
IncidentType C

FROM
(

select

COUNT(i.Id_num) as Incidents,

COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''A'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType A"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''B'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType B"
COUNT(case when i.INC_TYPE = ''C'' THEN 1
  end)
"IncidentType C"

FROM Table i

WHERE I.CALL_TIME  >= (now()-(''12 months'' ::interval))

GROUP BY i.Id_num

HAVING COUNT (i.Id_num) > 1

) i
```

The result is giving back a few duplicates

```
Id_num    Street   Incidents   IncidentType A IncidentType B IncidentType C
  32    back lane     5             3              0               2
  32    back lane     5             3              0               2
```

I've tried doing a `SELECT DISTINCT ON` the `Id_num` but still getting duplicates.

Comment: I don't see a `DISTINCT` anywhere in that query

Comment: Also, if you apply a DISTINCT in the subquery, your main query could still pull back duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Kalmino, that's what I was doing wrong,  distinct in the sub query.